# Who wins A,2,3,4,5 or 3,4,5,6,7 in Texas hold‘em?

Tags: texas-hold-em, rules, straight

Playing Texas hold‘em without 8 9 10.

The cards up are 2, 3, 4, 6, 7.
I have a A, 5 and the other person has a 5, J.

Who wins the straight?

The person with the Ace or the Jack?

Comment: What straights are available for either player?  Are we assuming the card order by rank is A234567JQKA?

Comment: If we assume that a card ranking of A234567JQKA. Then `4, 5, 6, 7, J` wins over `A, 2, 3, 4, 5`.

Answer (score -1):

you both have the same hand kickers do not play with straights. it can only be the best five cards playing the kickers makes it a six card hand and that is not at all how it works, top five cards to make the bext hand. you are both playing the same straight with the five. so the pot must be split. try not to over think these hands it is simple once you have a five card hand, it is done.

Comment: Who knows, there might be a straight 4567J with the rules that they play with.

Comment: I was once surprised playng Pia Gow poker, when my King high straight, lost to the dealers wheel, the dealer saying that the Ace played, I called BS and had a pit floorperson over. and was ruled against.